# How to render list of items inside Mat-Menu Angular/material2

Tags: angular, angular-material2

Back in materialc1 I was able to render a list of buttons inside my material menu as below:

```
  <md-menu>
  <md-button ng-click="vm.openMenu($mdMenu, $event)">     
     <md-icon md-svg-icon="extraIcons:toolbox" aria-label="Toolbox"></md-icon>
  </md-button>
  <md-menu-content>
    <md-menu-item ng-repeat="hi in vm.ListofPizza">          
     <md-button ng-click="vm.orderPizza(hi.id)">                        
         {{hi.name}}          
    </md-button>            
  </md-menu-item>
 </md-menu-content>
```

I am trying to do the same in material2/angular2 as shown below:

```
<button mat-fab color="primary" [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">
<mat-icon svgIcon="extraIcons:toolbox">
</mat-icon>   
</button>
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
<mat-menu-item *ngFor="let hi ofListofPizza">                 
<button mat-button> {{hi.name}}</button>
</mat-menu-item>
```

However this gives me below mentioned error:

> Can't have multiple template bindings on one element. Use only one
>   attribute named 'template' or prefixed with * ("
>
> ## menu="matMenu">

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: that syntax doesn't seem correct, it should be: `*ngFor="let hi of ListofPizza"`

Comment: You should use the `[mat-menu-item]` attribute instead of `[mat-button]`

Comment: @Edric I need to render buttons with names in list

Comment: @Und3rTow I did the change, but stil it doesnt work

Comment: @pankaj Can you check if a property `ofListofPizza` exists in your component code?

Comment: @Edric yeah what u said was correct .I used [mat-menu-item] attribute instead of [mat-button] and it worked.

Answer (score 7):

Thats how its supposed to be.

```
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
  <button mat-menu-item *ngFor="let item of ofListofPizza">
    {{ item.text }}
  </button>
</mat-menu>
```