# The mat-menu always appears at page end

Tags: angular

I implemented the `mat-menu` from angular material and the menu always appears at the page-end (code-below):

I have tried setting `z-index` and other `css` properties but the menu does not come where it originally should

```
HTML

<button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="main_menu">My menu</button>

      <mat-menu #main_menu="matMenu">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let mainItem of objectKeys(my_menu)">
          <button mat-menu-item [matMenuTriggerFor]="sub_menu">{{ mainItem }}</button>
          <mat-menu #sub_menu="matMenu">
             <button *ngFor="let subItem of my_menu[mainItem]" mat-menu-item>{{ subItem }}</button>
          </mat-menu>
        </ng-container>
      </mat-menu>



@Input() objectKeys = Object.keys;
  @Input() my_menu = {
    'main1': ['sub1', 'sub2'],
    'main2': ['sub1', 'sub2', 'sub3'],
  };
```

I expect the menu to appear around the button when clicked

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to render list of items inside Mat-Menu Angular/material2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48300898/how-to-render-list-of-items-inside-mat-menu-angular-material2)

Answer (score 4):

Faced similar issue.for me the solution was - adding @import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css'; to styles.

Comment: This is not the solution.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by setting an Angular Material default theme in angular.json.

```
"styles": ["./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css","projects/<project_name>/src/styles.css"]
```

Comment: This is not the solution.

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason MatMenu to be appeared in different place. There must be some css issues like `position: absolute` working behind it. Better go the console and elements tab and manually tried to off and on those properties to find out your problem.
To follow Example: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamic-mat-menu)

Comment: I tried looking through thue css and it didnt work. I could change the position by adding some css although but it not the default behaviour and neither it is responsive. I also tried putting the menu on a blank page and it worked as expected but as soon as i introduce another button before it in the page the whole thing shifts to the page end.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the issue. When relaunching `ng serve`, it worked.